# Как при ресайзе страницы перезапустить данную анимацию?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Подскажите пожалуйста как при ресайзе страницы перезапускать анимацию? Ну ли как при ресайзе страницы динамически изменять отступ на который сдвигается слайд ?

Пробовал так:

```
$(window).resize(function() {  
  setInterval('animation()',interval).stop(false,true);
  setInterval('animation()',interval); 
}).resize()
```

и так:

```
function animation(){
    if($(window).resize()){
        var margin = parseInt($('.slider').css('marginLeft'));  
      }
...............
};
```

Но почему-то не срабатывает.

```js
$(function() {      
  var width=$('.slider-box').width();                     // Ширина слайдера.
      interval = 2000;                                    // Интервал смены слайдов.
    speed = 1000
  $('.slider slider_item:last').clone().prependTo('.slider');     // Копия последнего слайда помещается в начало.
  $('.slider slider_item').eq(1).clone().appendTo('.slider');     // Копия первого слайда помещается в конец.  
  $('.slider').css('margin-left', -width);                // Контейнер .slider сдвигается влево на ширину одного слайда.
  $('.slider_item').css('width', width);
  setInterval('animation()',interval);                    // Запускается функция animation(), выполняющая смену слайдов.

 $(window).resize(function() {  
  slideWidth = $('.slider-box').outerWidth(),     
  width = $('.slider_item').css('width',slideWidth);
 }).resize()
 
});

function animation(){
 
   var margin = parseInt($('.slider').css('marginLeft'));  // Текущее смещение блока .slider
      width=$('.slider-box').width(),                     // Ширина слайдера.
      slidersAmount=$('.slider').children().length;       // Количество слайдов в слайдере.
  if(margin!=(-width*(slidersAmount-1)))                  // Если текущий слайд не последний,
  {
    margin=margin-width;                                  // то значение margin уменьшается на ширину слайда.
  }else{                                                  // Если показан последний слайд,
    $('.slider').css('margin-left', -width);              // то блок .slider возвращается в начальное положение,
    margin=-width*2;         
  }
  $('.slider').animate({marginLeft:margin},speed);          // Блок .slider смещается влево на 1 слайд.



};
```

```css
.slider-box{
  max-width:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
  outline:1px solid #cc0000;
}
.slider{
  position:relative;
  width:10000px;
}
.slider_item {
 float: left;
 width: 1000px;
}

.slider_item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-box">
  <div class="slider">

    <div class="slider_item"> 
     <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/maxresdefault-2-6.jpg" alt="" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://cdni.rt.com/russian/images/2017.04/article/58fe599bc3618843468b47c1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://cdn2.img.sputnik-georgia.com/images/23488/54/234885475.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

  <div class="slider_item"> 
     <img src="https://i2.rozetka.ua/goods/4684342/41683632_images_4684342448.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://thewire.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/space-1728314_1920.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самая большая проблема это то что во время анимации размер картинок нельзя оперативно поменять. Я менял внутри функции анимации.

Или если как нибудь сделать анимацию прерываемой, тогда можно было бы ее останавливать и оперативно пересчитывать местоположение и размер слайдов.

```js
$(function() {   
     resized=false; 
     var width=$('.slider-box').width();                     // Ширина слайдера.
      speed = 1000; // скорость смены слайдеров
      waiting = 1000; // пауза между сменой слайдеров
      interval = speed + waiting; // Суммарный интервал смены слайдов.
  $('.slider .slider_item').eq(0).clone().appendTo('.slider');     // Копия первого слайда помещается в конец.  
  $('.slider').css('margin-left', 0);                // Контейнер .slider сдвигается влево на ширину одного слайда.
  $('.slider_item').css('width', width);
  setInterval('animation()',interval);                    // Запускается функция animation(), выполняющая смену слайдов.
  
 $(window).resize(function() {  
  slideWidth = $('.slider-box').outerWidth();
  resized=true;
  //width = $('.slider_item').css('width',slideWidth); //нельзя менять ширину слайдов во время ресайза из за того, что в это время может происходить анимация и получится неровное смещение слайдеров. К тому же нужно пересчитывать отступ слайдеров слева.
 }).resize()
 
});

function animation(){
     var margin = parseInt($('.slider').css('marginLeft'));  // Текущее смещение блока .slider
      width=$('.slider-box').width();                     // Ширина слайдера.
      slidersAmount=$('.slider').children().length;       // Количество слайдов в слайдере.
  if (resized) {
    //если поменялись размеры окна слайдера, то пересчитываем отступ слайдеров и меняем их ширину.
    var widthslider=$('.slider_item').eq(1).width(); //старая ширина слайдеров
    var numslider=parseInt(-margin/widthslider); //номер текущего слайдера
    $('.slider_item').css('width',slideWidth); //меняем ширину слайдеров
    margin = -slideWidth * numslider; //считаем смещение слайдеров слева
    $('.slider').css('margin-left', margin); //меняем смещение слайдов слева
    resized=false;
  }
  if(margin>(-width*(slidersAmount - 1)))                  // Если текущий слайд не последний,
  {
    margin=margin-width;                                  // то значение margin уменьшается на ширину слайда.
  }else{                                                  // Если показан последний слайд,
    $('.slider').css('margin-left', 0);              // то блок .slider возвращается в начальное положение,
    margin=-width;         
  }
  $('.slider').animate({marginLeft:margin},speed);          // Блок .slider смещается влево на 1 слайд.

};
```

```css
.slider-box{
  max-width:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
  outline:1px solid #cc0000;
}
.slider{
  position:relative;
  width:10000px;
}
.slider_item {
 float: left;
 width: 1000px;
}

.slider_item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-box">
  <div class="slider">

    <div class="slider_item"> 
     <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/maxresdefault-2-6.jpg" alt="" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://cdni.rt.com/russian/images/2017.04/article/58fe599bc3618843468b47c1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://cdn2.img.sputnik-georgia.com/images/23488/54/234885475.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

  <div class="slider_item"> 
     <img src="https://i2.rozetka.ua/goods/4684342/41683632_images_4684342448.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://thewire.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/space-1728314_1920.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое то, что надо.